# What is a decent Mono Editor?

Tags: c#, editor, mono

I had been steering away from C# for a while, because it was "just a Windows thing", and it fell out of my current needs. However It's been gaining popularity and now with Mono catching up, it's becoming more attractive but I was wondering what IDE are people using to Code C#(with Mono) on *nix platforms.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic perhaps?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I think [MonoDevelop](http://monodevelop.com/Main_Page) is the most popular.

Comment: I really like Monodevelop, especially the recent releases.

Answer (score 5):

I use [Vim](http://www.vim.org) for all my *nix stuff. There's even a Vim plugin for VS ([ViEmu](http://www.viemu.com)) so you can use your Vim tricks from within the IDE as well.

Answer (score 2):

As [Mono For Linux Developers](http://www.mono-project.com/Mono_For_Linux_Developers) shows, there are at least 3 Eclispe plugins for C#.

Black Sun: http://black-sun.sourceforge.net/

Emonic Plugin: http://emonic.sourceforge.net/

C# Plugin from Improve Technologies: http://www.improve-technologies.com/alpha/esharp/

Answer (score 2):

I have been very unhappy with the editors (compared to VS.net), but I think under windows it's possible to develop .net with VS and then also test it against mono, to check if it works on both platforms.

Answer (score 2):

Strange, no one has mentioned Emacs yet.
[Emacs C# mode](http://www.emacswiki.org/cgi-bin/wiki/CSharpMode)

Answer (score 1):

I'm using [Textmate](http://macromates.com) on Mac OS X, it's the uber most awesomest editor on any platform, but it's not an IDE.

On X11 based systems i think i preferred Kate if i recall correctly.

Comment: I'm on a Mac at home so that's actually good to know! Unfortunately at work don't have a Mac :(

Comment: I've never tried Kate, but now that it has vi key bindings it might be worth a try. :)

Comment: TextMate doesn't have a C# bundle, does it?  I borrowed the C# bundle from the E editor and installed it on TextMate, but I've not really used it yet.

Answer (score 1):

[XDevelop](http://www.omnicore.com/en/xdevelop.htm) by Omnicore is another good alternative. It has some nice advanced features, it's multiplatform and it has a good Mono support.

Answer (score 1):

I have used SlickEdit for years on both Windows and Linux and like it very much.  It has good Emacs keybindings and runs well on both platforms.